# Can unbalanced classes introduce bias in a Random Forest model?

Tags: random-forest, bias, unbalanced-classes

I am working on a classification problem using Random Forest.

The training set has 600 instances and 16 attributes. The final class is an **Yes/No** answer. The ratio of "**Yes**" to "**No**" in the training set is around 5. Is it true (as I was told) that such a disparity (a lot more "**Yes**" than "**No**") can introduce a bias while predicting the class of an unknown instance using this model?

Comment: is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227088/when-should-i-balance-classes-in-a-training-data-set helpful?

Comment: [This may be helpful.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352) A similar simulation using RFs and your proposed scenario might be informative.